# How to split a column, by a specific word

Tags: excel

Scenario: I have a field for address, however we need to upload it to a database and the way it was formatted was the whole address, when in reality we needed, the address, state and zip separately.

attempts: I tried using the Text To Columns and Delimited function in excel but I can only split it by like, commas, spaces, etc.

Goal: Is there a way to split it using a word like, "FL" or "PORT SAINT LUCIE"?

Example of address: ="1459 SE BURKAY AVE PORT SAINT LUCIE FL 34563"

Comment: If its only one column, you could insert two helper columns. Else I don't see how you would do this without some sort of VBA-Makro

Comment: It is simple to split off the `state|zip` as that format is well defined. Due to the variability in city names, however, splitting that from the street address **reliably** requires some kind of lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to resolve this issue without VBA Makro is to find and replace the specific word preceded by a comma so as to choose your delimiter that way.